# How to alias `kj` to `kill -9 %?`(kill job)

Tags: alias

I want use `kj 1` for `kill -9 %1`

I try:

```
alias kj='kill -9 %'
```

but I can't use either `kj1` or `kj 1`.

It's there any way to do this?

Comment: Does this help? [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter)

Comment: Does it have to be an alias? To quote the bash manual `For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.`

Comment: thanks, it work, using `kj() { kill -9 %$@}`, and sometime need `unalias kj` first